# Qt WebKit and Permanent Cookies

Tags: c++, qt, cookies, webkit, qwebview

I have a mainwindow, in it, I have a single QWebView.
I want to make a certain website (www.kdkdkkd.com for instance) cookies permanent, so each time a user closes and repopens the browser he doesnt need to log in again.

Thanks,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to set your own "Cookie Jar".

1. Use [`QNetworkAccessManager::setCookieJar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setCookieJar) .
2. Extend `QNetworkCookieJar` - as it doesn't persist cookies by default when browser is closed:

> Once the `QNetworkCookieJar` object is
>   deleted, all cookies it held will be
>   discarded as well. If you want to save
>   the cookies, you should derive from
>   this class and implement the saving to
>   disk to your own storage format.
>   (From [`QNetworkCookieJar` documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkcookiejar.html).)

You can do this either by pushing to permanent storage on each [`QNetworkCookieJar::setCookiesFromUrl`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkcookiejar.html#setCookiesFromUrl) (safest but slowest) or only when the browser window is closed (faster overall but less safe as if you exit abnormally cookie jar won't be saved).

Note that [some cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Terminologies) are not supposed to be persisted, you can use [`QNetworkCookie::isSessionCookie`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork/qnetworkcookie.html#isSessionCookie) to determine this.

Comment: I Believe you meant: QNetworkCookieJar::setCookiesFromUrl I will check this now.

Comment: can you please explain with the code, I unable to store the cookies

Answer (score 4):

There is an official Qt Demo, called "[Browser](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-browser-example.html)". It implements a CookieJar class, which supports save and load of cookies to an .ini file, using the QSettings stack.

Answer (score 1):

Once cookie(s) registered in the NAM (NetworkAccessManager), set the webview to use it :

`myWebView->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(myNAM);`

Comment: Consider improving the formatting and being a bit descriptive.